# How do I assign a probability to a random interval within a switch statement using swift playground?

Tags: ios, swift, switch-statement, probability, swift-playground

My program simulates a soccer match. The default team plays a random team `var club: String` and each club will score a certain number of goals on an interval that is unique to the team.

I generated a random number  `teamN`  and the number is in the case statement below. If the random number is "1", then the opponent is  Manchester United. "2" is Tottenham etc.

Here is my code:

```
switch teamN { 
       case 1:
           club = manU
           goalsA = Int.random(in:0...2) // goalsA = # of goals Manchester United scored
           goalsH = Int.random(in:0...3) // goalsH = # of goals default team scored

       case 2:
           club = tott
           goalsA = Int.random(in:0...2)
           goalsH = Int.random(in:2...5)

       case 3:
           club = chel
           goalsA = Int.random(in:1...4)
           goalsH = Int.random(in:0...4)

       case 4:
           club = manC
           goalsA = Int.random(in:2...5)
           goalsH = Int.random(in:0...3)

       case 5:
           club = wat
           goalsA = Int.random(in:0...2)
           goalsH = Int.random(in:1...5)

       case 6:
           club = ever
           goalsA = Int.random(in:0...2)
           goalsH = Int.random(in:1...5)

       case 7:
           club = liv
           goalsA = Int.random(in:2...4)
           goalsH = Int.random(in:0...3)

       default:
           club = oops
           goalsA = Int.random(in:0...99)
           goalsH = Int.random(in:0...99) }
```

How do I assign a probability to a random number that is generated within an interval?

The goal is manU generates "0" 30%, "1" 50%, "2" 20%. How is this written in Swift playground?

Comment: Let me know if you need further help on this question

Answer (score 1):

You need to generate an Array according to probability

like

```
p(0) = 30%
p(1) = 50%
p(2) = 20%
```

so our array should be

```
let probability = [0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,2,2]
```

Now get Random number from this array instead

```
 if let getNumber = probability.randomElement() {

                    // assign that to your variable
                }
```

Comment: hello sir ... does this resolve the issue ? or you need more clarity ? :)

Comment: pleased to help you ...happy coding =)

Comment: if it resolve your issue you can accept and upvote for the appreciation...